# Compile ffmpeg with libfaac on Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, libfaac

I'm using ffmpeg, and I need it to have libfaac, and I understand the only way to make that happen is to compile it from source. I read a bunch of tutorials, and installed mingw, but I can't run the commands ./configure or make. Is there something I'm missing or another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I gave up on libfaac, and instead just added the following code: 
audio_codec: "aac", custom: "-strict experimental -q:v 5 -preset slow -g 30" to the arguments of encode_video for it to not to try to use libfaac.

Also, I had the wrong MinGW. I had the git version, but I needed MSys to run commands such as ./configure and make and make install.